# Can't npm link multiple packages

Tags: npm, npm-link

I'm getting a weird error while linking local packages:

I have 2 packages (let's call them A and B). When I link either one of those to my project using `npm link A` it works as intended. But then I try to link the other one as well using `npm link B` and it gets linked, but the link of **A** is gone. I get no error message, just the following:

> added 5 packages, removed 5 packages, changed 2 packages, and audited 121 packages in 5s
>
> 3 packages are looking for funding
> run `npm fund` for details

Previously this worked without any problem, but today I updated some dependencies with `npm update`. When I tried to relink my packages the problem occured.

Maybe it's worth mentioning that package B also links package A.

**Edit:** Solved it using `npm link A B`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Solved my issue using `npm link A B`.

Answer (score 0):

i have a similar problem, with a dozen modules, i ended up using mock-require

i made a little module that traverses the directory containing all my modules, and mocks all of them

this is the module, lets call it "@my-scope/mockModules"

```
const fs = require("fs-extra")
const path = require("path")
const mockRequire = require("mock-require")

// traverse directories,skipping "node_modules"
function traverseDir(directory, options, callback) {
  const files = fs.readdirSync(directory)
  
  for(const file of files) {
    const filepath = path.join(directory, file)
    const stat = fs.statSync(filepath)

    if (stat.isDirectory()) {
      if (options.exclude_folders === undefined || options.exclude_folders.indexOf(file) === -1) {
        traverseDir(filepath, options, callback)
      }
    } else {
      callback(file, filepath, directory)
    }
  }
}

// read all packages, to check if the module is in my scope
function getPackages(root) {
  const packages = []

  traverseDir(root, {
    exclude_folders: ["node_modules"]
  }, (name, path, directory) => {
    if(name === "package.json") {
      try {
        const content = require(path)

        packages.push({
          path,
          directory,
          content
        })
      } catch(error) {
        console.error(`could not open ${path}`)
      }
    }
  })

  return packages
}

// get an array of all packages, and paths for the modules in my scope, mock them using mock-require

function mockModules(rootFolder, scope) {
  let packages = getPackages(`${__dirname.split(rootFolder)[0]}${rootFolder}`)
  packages = packages.filter(pack => pack.content.name.indexOf(`${scope}/`) == 0)

  console.log("mocking")

  for(const pack of packages) {
    const path = `${pack.directory}/${pack.content.main}`
    console.log(`    ${pack.content.name} ${path}`)
    mockRequire(pack.content.name, path)
  }
}

module.exports = mockModules
```

and this is how to use it:

```
const mockModules = require("@my-scope/mockModules")
mockModules("my-scope", "name of root folder")
```